# dijit form select disregards sorting of dojo store memory datasource

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using a dojo store memory as a datasource for dijit form select.  The problem I'm having is that the select control ignores the sort I've set on the data store and instead sorts data on the label field.  I'm trying this:

```
 mhusStore = new Memory({ data: data, idProperty: "MHID", sort: [{ attribute: "SegIDOrder", descending: false }] }); //verified the sort is on SegIDOrder in debug mode (it also comes out of the db this way
 this.selectUSMAS.set("labelAttr", "MHID");
 //this.selectUSMAS.set("sort", "SegIDOrder");//tried this no result
 this.selectUSMAS.set("store", mhusStore);
```

any ideas how I can get the select to use the order of the memory store?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

already answered here:
[How to change order of elements in a dijit.form.Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910783/how-to-change-order-of-elements-in-a-dijit-form-select)

```
this.selectUSMAS.set("sortByLabel", false);
```